# How can I display two screenful of a file using the 'more' utility?

Tags: more

How can I display two screenful of a file using the `more` utility?

Is it something like :

```
more -num FILEname
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you could please explain more about your problem. Also, we do not do your homework for you. If you have an issue with the Operating system or a question of how to use this to accomplish your task, we can help, however, this is your assignment, not ours.

Comment: Thanks for the comment . the queestion says "Show how you can use the more utility to read the file: • display two screenfuls, "

Comment: Are you talking about using a command in the terminal to see more of a file?

Comment: yes i am talking about the more command which shows more of a file

Comment: @Abiral, What do you mean by: "two screenful "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `more` command takes data either from a specified file name. If no file name is given as argument, it reads from the standard input (necessary for using pipes).

```
more /PATH/TO/FILE
```

While `more` is displaying the file content, the most important keys to interact with it are:

- <kbd>RETURN</kbd>/<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to scroll down 1 line.
- <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to scroll down an entire page.
- <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit `more` and return to the shell prompt.
- <kbd>H</kbd> to display a short help page listing all keyboard commands.

If you need more information about `more`, read its manual page by typing `man more` or [its online manpage [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/more).